# Continue merge after switching to branch

Tags: git, smartgit

I'm a GIT newbie, coming from SVN.

I have a branch made a few weeks ago on a busy private gitlab repo.

Made several changes on it, commits & stages & unstaged.

Wished to bring the branch up-to-date as it had several dozens changes made by other people.

So, I did merge, several conflicts appeared, fixed the conflicts; an access denied error appeared on several directories changed by other persons.

Switched to master to see what they did, then back to my branch and puff, the branch had merged up-to-date but without my staged/unstaged changes.

I'm guessing those changes are lost forever, but I don't know for sure. Even showing staged changes is quasi dark magic for me.

So, questions, how do I find out if my staged/unstaged changes are lost?

Is it possible to switch from a branch in "merging" state to another branch without losing data?

Comment: Git should have *prevented* you from switching away from your in-progress merge to `master`, unless of course you used `-f` / `--force` to say: yes, I really mean to abandon my work-so-far. (Did you?)

Comment: As you seem to use SmartGit, check the Log, Branches view, Recyclable Commits.

Comment: I didn't use the CLI for switching, used SmartGit for that, no warning of any sort was displayed.

Comment: Checking Recyclable Commits, just a bunch of commits from other people, not mine sadly.

Comment: Ended giving up on this, deleted all my local branches, redoing work again. Git branches are not for me. Now every change I make I do that on a copy of the file tree, then merge back using Beyond Compare when going to commit.

Comment: Don't give up only because you got burnt once :) GIT branches are _very_ powerful. You cannot say you are a GIT user if you gave up on branches. In general SmartGit is really smart and it is quite difficult to lose your work completely. Try it again and pay attention to what you are doing. And remember, once you _commited_ something, it is almost impossible to lose it.